# Most efficient way of comparing the contents of two class instances in python

Tags: python, object, instance

I'm looking for the most efficient way of comparing the contents of two class instances. I have a list containing these class instances, and before appending to the list I want to determine if their property values are the same. This may seem trivial to most, but after perusing these forums I wasn't able specific to what I'm trying to do. Also note that I don't have an programming background.

This is what I have so far:

```
class BaseObject(object):
    def __init__(self, name=''):
        self._name = name


    def __repr__(self):
        return '<{0}: \'{1}\'>'.format(self.__class__.__name__, self.name)

    def _compare(self, other, *attributes):
        count = 0
        if isinstance(other, self.__class__):
            if len(attributes):
                for attrib in attributes:
                    if (attrib in self.__dict__.keys()) and (attrib in other.__dict__.keys()):
                        if self.__dict__[attrib] == other.__dict__[attrib]:
                            count += 1
                return (count == len(attributes))
            else:
                for attrib in self.__dict__.keys():
                    if (attrib in self.__dict__.keys()) and (attrib in other.__dict__.keys()):
                        if self.__dict__[attrib] == other.__dict__[attrib]:
                            count += 1
                return (count == len(self.__dict__.keys()))
    def _copy(self):
        return (copy.deepcopy(self))
```

Before adding to my list, I'd do something like:

```
found = False
for instance in myList:
    if instance._compare(newInstance): 
        found = True
        Break

if not found: myList.append(newInstance)
```

However I'm unclear whether this is the most efficient or python-ic way of comparing the contents of instances of the same class.

Comment: You should put them in a set and implement `__hash__` and `__eq__` in your class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Implement a [`__eq__` special method](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__) instead:

```
def __eq__(self, other, *attributes):
    if not isinstance(other, type(self)):
        return NotImplemented

    if attributes:
        d = float('NaN')  # default that won't compare equal, even with itself
        return all(self.__dict__.get(a, d) == other.__dict__.get(a, d) for a in attributes)

    return self.__dict__ == other.__dict__
```

Now you can just use:

```
if newInstance in myList:
```

and Python will automatically use the `__eq__` special method to test for equality.

In my version I retained the ability to pass in a limited set of attributes:

```
instance1.__eq__(instance2, 'attribute1', 'attribute2')
```

but using `all()` to make sure we only test as much as is needed.

Note that we return `NotImplemented`, a special singleton object to signal that the comparison is not supported; Python will ask the *other* object if it perhaps supports equality testing instead for that case.

Answer (score 7):

You can implement the [comparison magic method](http://www.rafekettler.com/magicmethods.html#comparisons) `__eq__(self, other)` for your class, then simply do

```
if instance == newInstance:
```

As you apparently don't know what attributes your instance will have, you could do:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    return isinstance(other, type(self)) and self.__dict__ == other.__dict__
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method has one major flaw: if you have reference cycles with classes that both derive from `BaseObject`, your comparison will never finish and die with a stack overflow.

In addition, two objects of different classes but with the same attribute values compare as equal. Trivial example: any instance of `BaseObject` with no attributes will compare as equal to any instance of a `BaseObject` subclass with no attributes (because if `issubclass(C, B)` and `a` is an instance of `C`, then `isinstance(a, B)` returns `True`).

Finally, rather than writing a custom `_compare` method, just call it `__eq__` and reap all the benefits of now being able to use the `==` operator (including contain testing in lists, container comparisons, etc.).

As a matter of personal preference, though, I'd stay away from that sort-of automatically-generated comparison, and explicitly compare explicit attributes.

Comment: *two objects of different classes but with the same attribute values compare as equal*: This is absolutely, patently *not true*. Instances of different classes never equal. Even the OP version does a `isinstance()` test first, and `object()` won't pass that test.

Comment: Whoops, my bad, I missed the ``isinstance`` check. Shouldn't comment on these things before the coffee has had the time to kick in. However, instances of different classes return ``None`` instead of 0, which may or may not be what you want.

Comment: What you want, really, is to return `NotImplemented` for those cases so that Python will look for `second.__eq__(first)`.

Comment: Wait, actually, instances of different classes can compare as equal, if and only if one is a subclass of the other (and both derive from ``BaseObject``).

Comment: Yes, and that is probably intended, provided they have the same attributes.

Comment: If it's not intended, by the way, just replace the ``isinstance`` check with ``if type(self) == type(other)``. It'll break duck typing, though, so don't do it unless necessary.

Comment: You'd use `type(self) is type(other)`; no need to do an equality test where classes are concerned.